# Squeak Smalltalk: Why reduction of a fraction does not happen after numerator and denominator values are modified in the inspect window?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

```
a := 12 / 24.
```

a is a variable assigned a fraction `12 / 24`. `1 / 2` is the answer when print. Now opening inspect pop up window, I alter the value of  numerator and denominator and guess the answer to be the same as  before, `1 / 2`. What truly happens is that the output stays `12 /  24`, which is kind of weird to me.

I have recorded a video to help understand this issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNj24f2wP0M

Why reduction of a fraction does not happen after numerator and denominator values are modified in the inspect window ??

Comment: Hi, please attempt to describe your problem without making people go to youtube. How do you attempt to alter the values? Do you apply the changes? What do you mean by "answer"? Do you mean `Transcript show: a` or similar? Have you tried debugging, i.e. stepping through your object's print methods?

Comment: Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942103/squeak-smalltalk-why-sometimes-the-reduced-method-doesnt-work      See Bert Freudenberg's answer which answers why fraction reduction does not automatically happen when numerator and denominator are manually created.  But still no why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe is correct and is the intended one.

As a developer you can modify objects in two ways:

1. Sending messages to them
2. Modifying their instance variables from an inspector

Method 1 is preferred because it conforms to the paradigm. So, why do we have method 2? Because when you open an inspector you somehow impersonate the object. In other words, you become the object under inspection and therefore you are entitled to modify yourself.

Of course, if you modify your internal state it is up to you to preserve your invariants. In the case of fractions, there are two invariants:

1. `denominator > 0`
2. `(numerator gcd: denominator) = 1`

In sum, the inspector will assume you know what you are doing and will let you modify all instance variables the way you want. When sending messages, however, the object should behave in such a way that its invariants are preserved.

Of course, there are private methods that should be handled with care (i.e., be only sent by public methods), but the general idea is that direct manipulation of objects is a good thing and presents no obstacle or safeguard.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on Pharo dialect, I believe Squeak is not strong different.
Because you divided Integers at the first time.
There is snippet from Integer>>/

```
(Fraction numerator: self denominator: aNumber) reduced
```

Pay attention to calling reduce method.

If you call reduce method after changing denominator/nominator at the Inspector tool, fraction object will be reduced too.