# Squeak Smalltalk, why sometimes the reduced method doesn't work?

Tags: smalltalk, fractions, squeak

```
(2332 / 2332) reduced 
(2332 / 2) reduced 
(2332 / 322) reduced  (1166/161)
(2332 / 3) reduced  (2332/3)
(2332 / 2432423) reduced  (2332/2432423)
```

Look at the above codes. The first and second, when printed, do not work.  The MessageNotUnderstood window pops up. And the 3rd, 4th, 5th code are okay. Results come out right.

Why does the `reduced` method not work?

Is it because the reduced method fails to handle final results which are integers like Uko guesses ?

Comment: Maybe the result of (2332 / 2332) is an integer? (which does not understand `reduced`

Comment: I think Uko was trying to give you a hint... look at the messageNotUnderstood a bit more closely and you should be able to figure this out yourself.

Comment: @Uko The result, however, returns `True` when passed the message `isFraction`.

Comment: @benrudgers if it is an integer and it responds `True` to `isFraction` I would say that it is a bug as you cannot replace every fraction with any integer and have it working

Comment: Squeak's code for `Integer`'s implementation `isFraction` explains the rational. `Integer` also has `floor` and `ceiling` per the Smalltalk specification. One person's bug is a feature per  Alan Kay, Dan Ingalls, and Adele Goldberg.

Comment: @Uko Since they represent Fraction with denominator 1, Integer is polymorphic to Fraction, so answering `true` to `isFraction` is not a bug. An Integer will respond to any public Fraction message. For private message like `reduced`, this is highly questionable though...

Comment: @aka.nice aha, I did not realize that `reduced` is private. Everything makes sense then

Comment: @Uko note: in order to avoid Integer answering true to `isFraction`, which sounds odd at first sight, VW defined `isRational`, as if there were a common superclass Rational to both Fraction and Integer. Then there is also the `asRational` conversion which can answer an Integer or Fraction. Maybe it's more proper, but at the end it's very same principle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fractions are reduced automatically in the `/` method. There is no need to send the `reduced` message.

E.g. if you print the result of

```
2 / 4
```

you get the reduced `(1/2)` automatically.

If you print the result of

```
2332 / 2332
```

it is reduced to `1` which is *not* a Fraction, but an Integer, and Integers do not understand the `reduced` message. That's why you get an error.

The only case when a Fraction is not automatically reduced is when you create it manually, as in

```
Fraction numerator: 2 denominator: 4
```

which will answer the non-reduced `(2/4)`. But in normal arithmetic expressions you never need to send `reduced`.

Comment: `Integer`s respond `True` to the message `isFraction`.  Keep in mind that One of the features of a good StackOverflow question is reducing the code down to the minimum that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because by default, the `Integer` class does not understand the message `reduced` in Squeak. *This despite members of Squeak's `Integer` class being fractions.*

```
5 isFraction "returns True"
```

The wonderful thing about Smalltalk is that if something does not work the way you want, you can change it. So if an `Integer` does not respond to the message `reduced` and you want it to, then you can add a `reduced` method to `Integer` with the expected behavior:

```
reduced
    "treat an integer like a fraction"
    ^ self
```

Adding methods to Classes is the way Smalltalk makes it easy to write expressive programs. For example, `Fractions` in GNU Smalltalk understand the message `reduce` but not the message `reduced` available in Squeak. Rather than trying to remember a meaningless difference, the programmer can simply make `reduced` available to fractions in GNU Smalltalk:

```
Fraction extend [
  "I am a synonym for reduce" 
  reduced [
    ^ self reduce
  ]
]
```

Likewise one can extend `Fraction` in Squeak to have a `reduce` method:

```
reduce
  "I am a synonym for reduced"
   ^ self reduced
```

The designers of Smalltalk made a language that let's programmers express themselves in the way that they think about the problem.

Comment: Yes you could do that, but since ‘reduced’ is a private method of Fractions, there really is no need.

Comment: @BertFreudenberg How does an `Integer` understand `reduced` otherwise?

Comment: @BertFreudenberg Treating built in functionality as privileged misses the point of Smalltalk.

Comment: Hi Ben, @BertFreudenberg is right. While it is ok to modify base classes, it is not so good to solve a problem by adding the selector that would otherwise generate a MNU. In this particular case the problem is a consequence of a bad use of `#reduced`, so the solution is to avoid such a bad use rather than adding a method to `Integer`. Are you familiar with the [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I am familiar with the XY problem. This is not one. Adding messages to Classes is the *sine qua non* of Smalltalk. One can port the culture of "UnPythonic" to Smalltalk, but that doesn't mean it is a good idea. One can write Smalltalk as if it is statically typed, that doesn't make that a good idea either. The reason `Integer` is easy to modify is because Smalltalk's designers thought it was a good way to write expressive programs. Are you familiar with the language Blub?

Comment: @benrudgers I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Blub. Note however that I'm not against modifying base classes or restricting any of the Smalltalk facilities. I'm only pointing out that the solution you proposed is not appropriate for the actual problem of this question because there is no reason for an `Integer` to receive `#reduced`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia [Blub](http://wiki.c2.com/?BlubParadox). I can easily envision a method that takes two numeric expressions evaluating to integers and applies `/` and `reduced`. The Blub approach would be to throw an `Exception` when `expression1 / expression2` evaluates to an `Integer` and write exception handling code. Alternatively, without an `Exception` the program will crash and Erlang aside, that's not usually what the programmer or the user wants. It's perhaps not what the OP wants either. Maybe it is the integer expressed as an integer. Maybe as a Fraction. Smalltalk will give either.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia For an example of adding methods to `Integer` for an arbitrary purpose that eases a programmer's life, Squeak has `benchFib`. It doesn't really cause any problems.

Comment: @benrudgers, as the other said, the problem is not reluctancy to extend a class, but extending it with a protocol that is not required neither appropriate for the class. You don't need to send reduced even to the fractions, as Bert explains in his answer. What is the point of send it to the integers? Would you implement it in UndefinedObject  also, just in case that someone sends it to nil?

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro Smalltalk is designed with the idea that the programmer decides what is and is not appropriate for a class based on the program they are writing. **One of the features of a good StackOverflow question is reducing the code down to the minimum that illustrates the problem**. The question shows *an expression* that might or might not evaluate to an `Integer`. Anyway in Squeak, `Integer`s are `Fraction`s and `5 isFraction` returns `true`.

Comment: For what it is worth, Ruby on Rails is so useful in part because it constantly over-rides the kernel method `method_missing` to create less surprising behavior. That's the beauty of everything being an object. But a person can write C or Python in any language.

Comment: A `reduced` method in the`Integer` class is no more or less inappropriate than `ceiling` and `floor` which are part of the Smalltalk specification.

Comment: @benrudgers if integers answer to isFraction with true, they are dooming themselves to respond #reduced and things like that. I don't understand nor share that decision (may be because it's mathematically correct) but as you said, that's in hands of the programmer